# Direct Burial Data cable

Tags: electrical

I need recommendations for a data cable that allows you to use it with direct burial. I am thinking CATA 5e.

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of data do you intend to send down this cable? Unless it's some sort of homebrew power-line/RS485 then no, that wire won't work for you.

Comment: Cat 5 won't transmit over standard power wires I think the last box of copper (not aluminum wire with a copper coat) cat6 was rated for direct sunlight , burial 1000' was around 120$ the aluminum stuff was 1/2 the cost.

Comment: If I were you I would get Ethernet to coax adapters for each end an bury RG6 instead.  Post on hardware recommendations stack to find out which Ethernet to coax adapter is best for your application.  Add a ground block to your RG6 also.

Comment: I would personally just buy direct burial cat 5e if the length is under 100m. If it is longer you will need to take a different approach, or attempt to drop the link speed.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules stating you can or cannot use any type of ethernet cable with UF wire. Technically, you can just lay ethernet cable on the ground, under the ground, or drape it from the trees. Keep in mind that if you don't protect your wire, it will degrade over time.

I'd recommend using a conduit with ethernet cable, buried at a reasonable depth and sealed at each mating point with pipe cement. You cannot run line voltage in this conduit, just so you know, but will be future proof if you want to add another line or use coax or fiber.

The UF wire you're talking about would be for carrying power and should be installed according to electrical code, probably 18" below grade. It would also require connections be made on either end for supplying and using the power.

Comment: +1 for "drape it over the trees". You would need ethernet cable that is outdoor-rated. Otherwise the water inside the conduit would wreck it. You can't keep water out of conduit, that's why you use wet-rated wire.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron and everyone! I was REALLY lost here. I will take all your recommendations and read the electrical code. I appreciate this.